# How to declare a variable holding a struct reference?

Tags: swift

Having this:

```
struct Person {
   var name = "Noname"
}

class World {
   var person: Person!

   func changePersonName(newName: String) {
      person.name = newName
   }
}

let you = Person(name: "Adam")
let world = World()
world.person = you
world.changePersonName("Eve")

println(you.name) // not "Eve", still "Adam"
```

In my case, I want `person.name` to become "Eve".

My question is how do I make the `person` variable in `World` not a copy, but a reference that I can modify its value like an object reference?

Comment: Where is `person` variable declared?

Comment: What is `person` variable?

Comment: I don't think this'll compile. Do you mean `println(world.person.name)`?

Comment: This is NOT REAL CODE. Show real code that actually compiles.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a 'reference type', rather than a 'value type', then use a `class`, rather than a `struct`.

```
class Person {
  var name = "Noname"
}

class World {
  var person = Person()
  changePersonName (name: String) {
    person.name = name
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that the only alternative? Because what I really need is a simple data holder, which struct are perfect for. I just need to be able to mutable the data in the original copy.

Comment: You CAN mutate the data in the copy held by `World`.  `Person` is defined as a `var` and the `Person` `name` field is mutable.  Thus `world.changePersonName(...)` works.  You can't, however, assign `you` to `world.person` and expect them to be identical; they aren't - on the assignment from `you` the `Person` is copied.

Answer (score 1):

As GoZoner has rightly said, if you want to have a side-effect of mutating a Person through some other reference, you need a class, not a struct. That is exactly one of the chief differences between a class and struct. A struct is a value type; a class is a reference type. Thus, starting with your example code and fixing it so that it actually compiles:

```
struct Person {
    var name = "Noname"
}
class World {
    var person: Person!
    func changePersonName(newName: String) {
        person.name = newName
    }
}
let you = Person(name: "Adam")
let world = World()
world.person = you
world.changePersonName("Eve")
print(you.name) // "Adam"
print(world.person.name) // "Eve"
```

So, you can see that `you` and `world.person` are *two different instances* of Person. They are not references to one and the same instance. That's usually regarded as a good thing, but if, for some reason, that's not what you want, then use a class:

```
class Person {
    var name = "Noname"
    init(name:String) {self.name = name}
}
class World {
    var person: Person!
    func changePersonName(newName: String) {
        person.name = newName
    }
}
let you = Person(name: "Adam")
let world = World()
world.person = you
world.changePersonName("Eve")
print(you.name) // "Eve"
print(world.person.name) // "Eve"
```

Comment: And see my book for a little essay on the difference between value types and reference types in Swift: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#SECreferenceTypes

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to have a reference to a struct then `UnsafeMutablePointer` is your choice, but I wouldn't recommend using it.

Answer (score 0):

As s1ddok pointed out, you can use `UnsafeMutablePointer`:

```
struct Person {
    var name = "Noname"
}

class World {
    var person: UnsafeMutablePointer<Person>!

    func changePersonName(newName: String) {
        person.memory.name = newName
    }
}

var you = Person(name: "Adam")
var ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<Person>.alloc(1)
ptr.initialize(you)
let world = World()
world.person = ptr
world.changePersonName("Eve")

print(ptr.memory.name)
```